# Two dimensional array from single dimensional arrays not working

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
A=['a','b','c',...] 
B=[1,2,3...]
```

Array length of A=B. 
I need a resultant array like this

```
R= [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],...]
```

I tried like this

```
for(var i=0;i< A.length;i++)
{
 R.push(A[i],B[i])
}
```

It is not working. What should I do?? I am new to this. Please help me. I searched a lot, but not getting. Help me  dear friends!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
R.push(A[i],B[i])
```

to

```
R.push([A[i],B[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want R[] to be a 2-Dimensional array, you would have to change the program slightly to this:

```
R.push([A[i], B[i]])
```